# AudioKit: How to record OWN app audio output on ios?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I want to get my OWN app audio output (for example currently playing video in UIWebView) and save it to file. How to create a AudioKit Node for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Just because your app has audio doesn't really mean you have control of the audio if you're just using web views for instance. Another example is using the speech synthesizer in iOS - the app utters the speech, but you can't direct that audio anywhere except to the user's speaker.

Comment: Thank you for reply